# Trigger - SQL Statement Ignored Error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a trigger to automatically update the status level of users in my database. The status level is based on the amount of revenue a user generates. This is what I have come up with so far.

```
create or replace trigger update_hirer_status
after insert or update of payment_id, status_id on payments
for each row
declare 
user_id_temp number := 0;
total_amount number := 0;

begin
select external_users.external_user_id into user_id_temp
from external_users
join financial_accounts
using (external_user_id)
join payments
on financial_accounts.account_number = payments.sending_account_number
where financial_accounts.account_number = payments.sending_account_number;

select sum(amount) into total_amount
from payments
join
financial_accounts
on payments.sending_account_number = financial_accounts.account_number
join external_users
on financial_accounts.external_user_id = external_users.external_user_id
where payments.status_id = 1
and financial_accounts.external_user_id = user_id_temp;

if total_amount >= 2000
then update external_users
set status_id = 4
where external_user_id = user_id_temp;

elsif total_amount >= 500
then update external_users
set status_id = 3
where external_user_id = user_id_temp;

elsif total_amount >= 100
then update external_users
set status_id = 2
where external_user_id = user_id_temp;

end if;
end;
```

When trying to create this trigger I receive the following error message:

Error at line 6: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

```
declare
user_id_temp number := 0;
total_amount number := 0;
begin
select external_users.external_user_id into user_id_temp
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be? This is the first time I have tried creating a trigger so feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: That's the only error - you don't get a block of them, one of which should highlight the real problem? How and where are you running this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the following statement

```
select external_users.external_user_id into user_id_temp
  from external_users
  join financial_accounts
    using (external_user_id)
  join payments
    on financial_accounts.account_number = payments.sending_account_number
  where financial_accounts.account_number = payments.sending_account_number;
```

the `USING` clause merges `EXTERNAL_USERS.EXTERNAL_USER_ID` and `FINANCIAL_ACCOUNTS.EXTERNAL_USER_ID` into a single `EXTERNAL_USER_ID`field, and thus you can no longer say `EXTERNAL_USERS.EXTERNAL_USER_ID`. Change the statement to

```
select external_user_id
  into user_id_temp
  from external_users
  join financial_accounts
    using (external_user_id)
  join payments
    on financial_accounts.account_number = payments.sending_account_number
  where financial_accounts.account_number = payments.sending_account_number;
```

and give it a try.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this and the trigger was successfully created. Unfortunately it's not actually working when I update or insert into the payments table though.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but would be a good subject for another question. Create a new question, post the trigger code and any related info, and perhaps someone can offer some ideas.